# Javac command in command prompt does not execute file

Tags: java, cmd, compiler-errors, runtime-error

Ok I am new to Java and was trying to run a java program from the command prompt (because Sublime compiles and runs in it's little thing but doesn't allow for user inputs and stuff).

I set the command prompt to the folder which I have my file which is called Learner.java.

```
C:\Users\jonat>cd C:\Users\jonat\Desktop\Projects\Java
```

I have set a path for my JDK bin in my environment variables and created a JAVA_HOME variable with a value to the JDK bin (which some other post suggested).

Before I go into the issue, this is my code:

```
class Learner {
  public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    System.out.println("Jonathan's Project");
  }
}
```

As you can see, it is a simple print project with "Jonathan's Project" as the output. I have already tested this in Sublime 3 and it compiles and prints.

HOWEVER, when I call upon the program in cmd prompt, it just runs for a second or so and then skips a line and starts a new command line. No "Jonathan's Project" prints which is weird because the cmd prompt shows no error and it acts like it ran the program but nothing was run...

Comment: Hint: `javac` invokes java compiler.

Comment: Compiling your program is not the same as running your program.

Answer (score 1):

`javac` is to compile the program. To run the program, use the`java` command. 
You need to compile before running the program.

Also, with `javac`, you need to write `javac Learner.java`, and with `java` you only need `java Learner`.

To learn more about compilation and execution check out this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compilation-execution-java-program/